# Positive identification of a fillable PDF form among non-PDF form files

Tags: parsing, pdf

I'm looking for an programmatic approach to positively identify fillable PDF form(s) among non-PDF form files.

The options that I believe are available are:

- Parse the PDF code and content
- Parse the file for signature identification with a hex capable language such as Python
- Parse the file with a hex capable language such as Python to flag telltale signs

Comment: Not a full-proof test, but for the first option you could try searching the string AcroForm in the file. The two other options can make this question off-topic, since this website is for programming questions only.

Comment: The reason why this was asked is because there is a need to audit and flag files of interest for approval process that may be requesting for information that could violate policies.  I'm sure this is important to many organizations and also for those that just like to play around.  Forensic analysts may also find this useful as well as those doing emergency data recovery.

Comment: I am just warning you. The admins here usually won't care how useful your question could be. If it is not about programming, it is almost sure it will get closed/deleted.

Comment: I guess the hex editor can be substituted with some hex library to put it back into acceptable scope question topic.  Updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the Catalog > AcroForm > Fields Array has at least one Dictionary element, the PDF is a fillable form.  For bonus points, you could do some level of validation that the Field Dictionary is legit (validate Type and Subtype for example).